# Filtering out another dataframe based on selected hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to filter out my dataframe based only on 3 hourly frequency, meaning starting from 0000hr, 0300hr, 0900hr, 1200hr, 1500hr, 1800hr, 2100hr, so on and so forth.

A sample of my dataframe would look like this

```
Time                   A
2019-05-25 03:54:00    1
2019-05-25 03:57:00    2
2019-05-25 04:00:00    3
...
2020-05-25 03:54:00    4
2020-05-25 03:57:00    5
2020-05-25 04:00:00    6
```

Desired output:

```
Time                   A
2019-05-25 06:00:00    1
2019-05-25 09:00:00    2
2019-05-25 12:00:00    3
...
2020-05-25 00:00:00    4
2020-05-25 03:00:00    5
2020-05-25 06:00:00    6
2020-05-25 09:00:00    6
2020-05-25 12:00:00    6
2020-05-25 15:00:00    6
2020-05-25 18:00:00    6
2020-05-25 21:00:00    6
2020-05-26 00:00:00    6
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by filtering out ?   Group all entries into these 3-hour intervals or retain only entries exactly on these 00, 03, 06 hours ?

Comment: Yes, I meant retain entries exactly on these time intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a date range with 3 hours interval with [`pd.date_range()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then filter your dataframe with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), as follows:

```
date_rng_3H = pd.date_range(start=df['Time'].dt.date.min(), end=df['Time'].dt.date.max() + pd.DateOffset(days=1), freq='3H')

df_out = df.loc[df['Time'].isin(date_rng_3H)]
```

**Input data:**

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2019-05-25 03:54:00', end='2020-05-25 04:00:00', freq='3T')

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': date_rng, 'A': np.random.randint(1, 6, len(date_rng))})

    Time                     A
0   2019-05-25 03:54:00      3
1   2019-05-25 03:57:00      5
2   2019-05-25 04:00:00      3
3   2019-05-25 04:03:00      2
4   2019-05-25 04:06:00      4
... ... ...
175678  2020-05-25 03:48:00  2
175679  2020-05-25 03:51:00  1
175680  2020-05-25 03:54:00  2
175681  2020-05-25 03:57:00  2
175682  2020-05-25 04:00:00  1
175683 rows × 2 columns
```

**Output:**

```
print(df_out)


    Time                     A
42  2019-05-25 06:00:00      4
102 2019-05-25 09:00:00      2
162 2019-05-25 12:00:00      1
222 2019-05-25 15:00:00      3
282 2019-05-25 18:00:00      5
... ... ...
175422  2020-05-24 15:00:00  1
175482  2020-05-24 18:00:00  5
175542  2020-05-24 21:00:00  2
175602  2020-05-25 00:00:00  3
175662  2020-05-25 03:00:00  3
```